# Не могу передать по ссылке

Tags: c++

Почему не компилируется код? Как исправить?

**main.cpp**

```
// код ...


void foo(A& a) {
// код ...
}

// код ...

#include "A.hpp"


int main() {
    A a;
    foo(a);
}
```

**A.hpp**

```
#ifndef A_HPP
#define A_HPP

class A {
// код ...
};

// код ...

#define void NULL

// код ...

#endif
```

Comment: кажется Вы перепутали поля *имя пользователя* и *заголовок вопроса*

Comment: @Alex исправило

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что сначала надо сущность объявить, а потом использовать...

```
#include "A.hpp"
```

должно идти перед

```
void foo(A& a) {
// код ...
}
```

И еще - за вот такое

```
#define void NULL
```

малолетним программистам копчик массируют...

P.S. Тут некоторые намеков не понимают :) - так вот, вот этого

```
#define void NULL
```

быть вообще не должно! Ни до, ни после!

Comment: не компилируется так из-за #define void NULL

Comment: Это заслуживает приз зрительских симпатий :)

Comment: я не могу изменить A.hpp надо только после включать инчае ошибка

Comment: что делать не работает если написать до

Comment: Хорошо, говорю прямо, раз намек не дошел: уберите идиотскую - иначе не скажешь - строку `#define void NULL`!!